# Expanded usercard bug in Safari 7.0

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-card, safari

<strike>Expanded usercard is showing up at top left corner in Safari 7.0. I think this is bug and usercard should show up next to mouse cursor instead.</strike>

[image]

<strike>Not only in meta, also in other sites like StackOverflow</strike>

[image]

Edit: Oh, it's safari extension which causes that problem, disabling extensions solves this problem. Weird because other popups like tag descriptions works perfectly, but my bad.

Edit 2: It seems that blocking social media buttons causes this problem. I hate all those social media sites, like twitter, facebook, google+ etc. so blocked those +1, like etc buttons.

Comment: can't reproduce, here it works fine in safari. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Azik updated my question, extension problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is don't use that user script :)  It would appear it's blocking some classes/elements we use that aren't related.  This is always a risk with pattern matching, you'll nuke legitimate things in the process.